# Turn physics proccesses off and on?

Tags: workflow, physics, performance

Is there an easy way to, while keeping all of the physics settings the same, turn off the physics processing? Essentially, I have a huge scene with a ton of physics and I'm not ready to bake it yet but with all of these simulations going at the same time, workflow has slowed to a crawl. I want to tell blender to just process the simulation I'm currently working on but without it messing up my other physics! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, click the eye icon in the physics panel or the modifiers panel to disable the simulation in the viewport:

[image]

Clicking the camera icon disables the simulation in the render.

Comment: While this does work, I have about a thousand (Not exaggerating) separate pieces all undergoing physics. Is there any hope that I can batch select and turn them off without screwing things up?

Comment: If you can select them (there are some tricks you can probably do, but what will work depends on your specific situation), right click on the eye button and click *Copy to selected* to copy the setting to all the selected objects.

Comment: Usually the copy to selected will also copy over the rest of the physics settings as well. I have not tried just right clicking a single setting. Will singling things out like that work?

Comment: @Daniel ? AFAIK It *only* copies single settings.. This is different from the *copy from active* button in the tool shelf